# Avoiding Left Recursion parsing Lambda Calculus while maintaining Left Associativity

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda-calculus, peg, left-recursion

I am trying to parse lambda calculus terms into AST leveraging JavaScript and PEG.JS.  The grammar is fairly easy:

```
/*****************************************************************
        t ::=
                x                                       variable
                λx.t                                    abstraction
                t t                                     application
*****************************************************************/
```

From which I have coded out the PEG:

```
TERM "term"
    = ABSTRACTION
    / APPLICATION
    / VARIABLE

APPLICATION "application"
    /*****************************************************************
        application ::= t t
    *****************************************************************/
    = APPLICATION_W_PARENS
    / APPLICATION_WO_PARENS

ABSTRACTION "abstraction"
    /*****************************************************************
        abstraction ::= λx.t
    *****************************************************************/
    = ABSTRACTION_W_PARENS
    / ABSTRACTION_WO_PARENS

VARIABLE "variable"
    /*****************************************************************
        variable ::= x
    *****************************************************************/
    =  x:CHARACTER
    {
        return Variable(location(), x)
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Application
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ABSTRACTION_OR_VARIABLE
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // "Left recursive grammar" workaround "term term" enters a loop
    //      assuming the left side cannot match Application
    //      remediates the left recursion issue
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    = ABSTRACTION / VARIABLE

APPLICATION_W_PARENS
    /*****************************************************************
        '(' -> Abstraction | Variable -> Term -> ')'
    *****************************************************************/
    = L_PARENS lhs:ABSTRACTION_OR_VARIABLE rhs:TERM R_PARENS
    {
        return Application(location(), lhs, rhs, true)
    }

APPLICATION_WO_PARENS
    /*****************************************************************
        Abstraction | Variable -> Term
    *****************************************************************/
    = lhs:ABSTRACTION_OR_VARIABLE rhs:TERM
    {
        return Application(location(), lhs, rhs, false)
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Abstraction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ABSTRACTION_W_PARENS "abstraction"
    /*****************************************************************
            '(' -> 'λ' -> Variable -> '.' -> TERM -> ')'
    *****************************************************************/
    = L_PARENS LAMBDA x:CHARACTER DOT term:TERM R_PARENS
    {
        return Abstraction(location(), x, term, true)
    }

ABSTRACTION_WO_PARENS
    /*****************************************************************
            'λ' -> Variable -> '.' -> Term
    *****************************************************************/
   = LAMBDA x:CHARACTER DOT term:TERM
   {
        return Abstraction(location(), x, term, false)
   }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Atoms
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

LAMBDA "lambda"
    = 'λ'

L_PARENS "lParens"
    = '('

R_PARENS "rParens"
    = ')'

DOT "dot"
    = [\.]

CHARACTER "character"
    = [A-Za-z]
    {
        return text().trim() ;
    }
```

This compiles and runs fine on simple input.  As I start to push through the examples to test the implementation I see some issues.  Given the term

```
λl.λm.λn.lmn
```

It parses into

```
{
    "expr": "λl.λm.λn.lmn",
    "ast": " Abstraction( l,  Abstraction( m,  Abstraction( n, Application(  Variable( l ), Application(  Variable( m ),  Variable( n ) ) ) ) ) )"
}
```

The problem is in *Left Application* **m** should be applied to **l** and then **n** to that result.  As you can see by the printout of the AST that **n** is applied to **m** and that result is applied to **l** which is not correct.

IF I change the rule that is in place to prevent left recursion issues where the application assumes that the left side is only a variable or an abstraction to include the possibility of application - then there is the recursion issue.

I introduced the concept of parens - but I stopped integrating them in.  I really don't want them in the grammar.

1. Can we fix this in the PEG.JS?
2. OR Should I rewrite the construction of the Application Object (hack)?
3. OR Is there a better way to parse this - e.g. roll a custom parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Flawed Approach**: One approach I toyed with was to force the match of more than two Variables | Abstractions in a row and left apply them

```
APP_2
    = lhs:ABSTRACTION_OR_VARIABLE rhs:ABSTRACTION_OR_VARIABLE
    {
        return Application(location(), lhs, rhs, false, "APP2")
    }

APP_3
    = lhs:APP_2 rhs:TERM
    {
        return Application(location(), lhs, rhs, false, "APP3")
    }

APPLICATION_WO_PARENS
    = APP_3
    / APP_2
```

Which looks like it works when the application is of three terms. When there are four we get a balanced tree of 2 levels where we want an unbalanced tree of three levels... SO this is the incorrect output of the previous PEG (with input of lmno):

```
{
    "expr": "lmno",
    "ast": "Application::APP3( 
              Application::APP2(  Variable(l),  Variable(m) ),
              Application::APP2(  Variable(n),  Variable(o) ) 
            )"
}
```

So I could build out any number of APP_2 ... APP_99 rules and force the left application.  Which would work - until I exceeded the 99 (or whatever) number of applications.  The solution would be a real hack and fragile.

---

**Working Hack Approach**: Wanting to hack something together I changed the approach to matching an array of terms as an application:

```
APP_ARR
    = terms:ABSTRACTION_OR_VARIABLE*
   {
        return reduceTerms(location(), terms)
   }

APPLICATION_WO_PARENS
    = APP_ARR
```

This approach requires me to write a bit of code to build the structure (reduceTerms) which I was trying to avoid.  Here is the code:

```
const reduceTerms = function(info, terms){
    const initialLhs = terms.shift()
    const initialRhs = terms.shift()
    const initialApp = Application(info, initialLhs, initialRhs, false, 'reduceTerms')

    const appAll = terms.reduce(
        (lhs, rhs) => Application(info, lhs, rhs, false, 'reduceTerms'),
        initialApp
    )

    return appAll ;
}
```

Please ignore the boolean and 'reduceTerms' character string.  The boolean is used to indicate whether this application was contained within parens (going to remove the parens concept until I encounter it later in the book). The character string is a label on how/where I constructed this instance of the Application node (to debug how the parser is applying the rules).

The reduceTerms function is a simple reduction of an array into the Application tree applying the terms in left application.  The initial object is an Application of the left two items in the *terms* array.  The reducing function will take that initial object as the *lhs* and the next term up as the *rhs*, which is exactly what you want. Here is the *working* output:

```
{
    "expr": "lmno",
    "ast": "Application::reduceTerms( 
              Application::reduceTerms( 
                Application::reduceTerms(  Variable(l),  Variable(m) ),  
              Variable(n) ),  
            Variable(o) )"
}
```

The one problem here is that I would need to do some extra work to get the *info* object to accurately reflect the matches. In this version the *info* object contains the range from which all the terms were matched out of. While not critical it would be nice to have that all tie out.

---

So I am still looking for a solution that does this inside of the PEG without matching on the array and reducing into a tree.

---

**Progress on removing the left recursion**: Using the published approach translating

```
A -> A α | β
```

to

```
A -> β A'
A' -> α A' | ε
```

In PEG I have

```
TERM_OR_VARIABLE
    = L_PARENS TERM R_PARENS
    / VARIABLE

APP
   = lhs:TERM_OR_VARIABLE rhs:APP_
   {
       return Application(location(), lhs, rhs, false, "APP")
   }

APP_
    = lhs:TERM_OR_VARIABLE rhs:APP_
    {
        return Application(location(), lhs, rhs, false, "APP_")
    }
    / lhs:TERM_OR_VARIABLE END
    {
        return lhs
    }
    / END

END
    = !.

APPLICATION_WO_PARENS
    = APP
```

I am now able to parse the application *lmno* but the AST is right to left application

```
Application::APP(  
    Variable(l), 
    Application::APP_(  
       Variable(m), 
       Application::APP_(  
          Variable(n),  
          Variable(o) 
       ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: I am marking correct as I resigned my self to the array reduce as the best selection for me at this time.

Comment: Linking to an article I wrote on my work w/ source https://medium.com/@akaphenom/pilgrimage-to-lambda-calculus-54e589afeebd